# bottom navigation пропадают буквы

Tags: android, kotlin, bottom-navigation-view

Хочу сделать вот такую навигацию

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но получается вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Куда спрятались буквы? Исчезают буквы при добавлении элементов

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно добавить в разметку менюшки `app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"`

Comment: В русском интернете не смог сформулировать данный вопрос. Спасибо! Может пригодится кому-то